# Foundation 5 JS plugins don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I've been using Foundation for a couple of years, but haven't had an issue with the JS plugins until I just upgraded to Foundation 5. I've run bower 'bundle' and updated the file paths, but no matter what, plugins like Reveal and Joyride simply never fire unless manually called via the console. The dev tools aren't throwing any errors or showing any missing files, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Here's my super basic markup:

```
<html class='no-js' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
    <link href='stylesheets/app.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src='bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js'></script>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='small-12 columns'>
        <a data_reveal_id='myModal' href='#'>
          <button>Hello!</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='reveal-modal' data_reveal id='myModal'>
      <h1>I'm a modal!</h1>
      <a class='close-reveal-modal'>&#215;</a>
    </div>
    <script src='bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js'></script>
    <script src='bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js'></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would HUGELY appreciated! I've tried checking every other thread I can find but I haven't seen a similar issue.

Comment: Are you sure there's no 404 errors in the Network panel?

Comment: @raina77ow - nope, nothing in console, and nothing in Network (everything's being loaded)

Comment: please try to reproduce the error in a fiddle and share with us.

Answer (score 0):

You got 2 errors in your code.

1. Dont use underscores, use hyphens for the data attribute to work
   correctly
2. Dont put your button inside an anchor tag, the button is sufficent.

Like so:

```
<html class='no-js' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
    <link href='stylesheets/app.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src='bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js'></script>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='small-12 columns'>
        <!--<a data_reveal_id='myModal' href='#'>-->
          <button data-reveal-id='myModal'>Hello!</button>
        <!--</a>-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='reveal-modal' data-reveal id='myModal'>
      <h1>I'm a modal!</h1>
      <a class='close-reveal-modal'>&#215;</a>
    </div>
    <script src='bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js'></script>
    <script src='bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js'></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```